# Fit data with NormalDistribution

Tags: fitting, data

Good day to all!

I have some data that I would like to fit with a normal distribution:

```
Ftab = {0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,2.15693*^18,5.87542*^18,9.75208*^18,1.35966*^19,1.74086*^19,2.14985*^19,2.57867*^19,3.06021*^19,3.56339*^19,4.08717*^19,4.63014*^19,5.14949*^19,6.30563*^19,9.59017*^19,1.29848*^20,1.64222*^20,1.98359*^20,2.31568*^20,2.6649*^20,2.93886*^20,3.12365*^20,3.30426*^20,3.47828*^20,3.64334*^20,3.79713*^20,3.93726*^20,4.08463*^20,4.28421*^20,4.46295*^20,4.61719*^20,4.74343*^20,4.83849*^20,4.89959*^20,4.89155*^20,4.8162*^20,4.70771*^20,4.56704*^20,4.3959*^20,4.19674*^20,3.97271*^20,3.72758*^20,3.46562*^20,3.16687*^20,2.8565*^20,2.54801*^20,2.24653*^20,1.95684*^20,1.68313*^20,1.42884*^20,1.19657*^20,9.88005*^19,7.96794*^19,6.3389*^19,4.97365*^19,3.84731*^19,2.93283*^19,2.20236*^19,1.62852*^19,1.1853*^19,8.48836*^18,5.91329*^18,4.08807*^18,2.77304*^18,1.84785*^18,1.20917*^18,7.76709*^17,4.89578*^17,3.02707*^17,1.83532*^17,1.09078*^17,6.36243*^16,3.63769*^16,2.037*^16,1.11682*^16,5.99341*^15,3.14729*^15,1.61677*^15,8.12254*^14,3.98982*^14,1.91568*^14,8.88572*^13,4.09217*^13,1.8515*^13,8.2291*^12,3.59248*^12,1.5403*^12,6.48546*^11,2.68139*^11,1.08849*^11,4.33808*^10,1.69724*^10,6.5182*^9,2.45709*^9,9.09066*^8,3.30082*^8,1.1809*^8,4.14603*^7,1.42842*^7,4.82907*^6,1.60192*^6,521400.,166763.,52889.9,16659.9,5212.2,1619.74,499.999,153.326,46.7099,14.1375,4.25138,1.27029,0.37715,0.111272,0.0326245,0.00950618,0.00275293,0.000792364,0.000227188,0.0000647492,0.000018344,5.16638*^-6,1.44746*^-6,4.04993*^-7,1.13245*^-7,3.16491*^-8,8.84104*^-9,2.48832*^-9,6.89887*^-10,1.92817*^-10,5.3877*^-11,1.50516*^-11,4.19478*^-12,1.1663*^-12,3.23529*^-13,8.95459*^-14,2.47316*^-14,6.81648*^-15,1.87536*^-15,5.15688*^-16,1.4177*^-16,3.89675*^-17,1.07096*^-17,2.94315*^-18,8.08787*^-19,2.22263*^-19,6.10835*^-20,1.67907*^-20,4.61637*^-21,1.26962*^-21,3.49314*^-22,9.61425*^-23,2.64971*^-23,7.32514*^-24,2.03164*^-24,5.65294*^-25,1.57813*^-25,4.42091*^-26,1.24274*^-26,3.50629*^-27,9.93014*^-28,2.8206*^-28,8.03604*^-29,2.29661*^-29,6.58427*^-30,1.89381*^-30,5.46852*^-31,1.58502*^-31,4.61092*^-32,1.34633*^-32,3.94568*^-33,1.16067*^-33,3.42722*^-34,1.01591*^-34,3.02326*^-35,9.03278*^-36,2.7097*^-36,8.16238*^-37,2.46913*^-37,7.50123*^-38,2.28876*^-38,7.01369*^-39,2.15558*^-39,6.63493*^-40,2.04544*^-40,6.31601*^-41,1.95371*^-41,6.05436*^-42,1.87969*^-42,5.84708*^-43,1.82244*^-43,5.69175*^-44,1.78132*^-44,5.58675*^-45,1.75599*^-45,5.53156*^-46,1.74646*^-46,5.52685*^-47,1.75316*^-47,5.57461*^-48,1.777*^-48,5.67974*^-49,1.82043*^-49,5.85113*^-50,1.8926*^-50,6.20322*^-51,2.03881*^-51,6.71987*^-52,2.22122*^-52,7.36367*^-53,2.44869*^-53,8.1692*^-54,2.73435*^-54,9.18288*^-55,3.0944*^-55,1.04633*^-55,3.55043*^-56,1.20901*^-56,4.13181*^-57,1.41721*^-57,4.87905*^-58,1.68614*^-58,5.79854*^-59,1.99629*^-59,6.90152*^-60,2.3963*^-60,8.35665*^-61,2.92717*^-61,1.03004*^-61,3.64151*^-62,1.29343*^-62,4.60958*^-63,1.64609*^-63,5.89022*^-64,2.11209*^-64,7.58939*^-65,2.73295*^-65,9.86276*^-66,3.56716*^-66,1.29306*^-66,4.69784*^-67,1.71071*^-67,6.24407*^-68,2.28447*^-68,8.37801*^-69,3.08*^-69,1.13508*^-69,4.19358*^-70,1.55323*^-70,5.7676*^-71,2.14725*^-71,8.0159*^-72,3.00073*^-72,1.12647*^-72,4.24074*^-73,1.60107*^-73,6.06226*^-74,2.30213*^-74,8.76822*^-75,3.34958*^-75,1.28346*^-75,4.93351*^-76,1.90206*^-76,7.34281*^-77,2.83763*^-77,1.09777*^-77,4.25153*^-78,1.64839*^-78,6.39831*^-79,2.48641*^-79,9.67365*^-80,3.76821*^-80,1.46972*^-80,5.73981*^-81,2.24458*^-81,8.78933*^-82,3.44642*^-82,1.35326*^-82,5.32112*^-83,2.09529*^-83,8.26251*^-84,3.26937*^-84,1.30314*^-84,5.17437*^-85,2.04684*^-85,8.1092*^-86,3.21771*^-86,1.2788*^-86,5.09376*^-87,2.03636*^-87,8.15419*^-88,3.27042*^-88,1.31379*^-88,5.28637*^-89,2.13063*^-89,8.60167*^-90,3.47851*^-90,1.40912*^-90,5.7181*^-91,2.32444*^-91,9.46562*^-92,3.8613*^-92,1.57788*^-92,6.45927*^-93,2.64891*^-93,1.08826*^-93,4.4791*^-94,1.84692*^-94,7.62982*^-95,3.15773*^-95,1.30778*^-95,5.41761*^-96,2.24526*^-96,9.30955*^-97,3.86189*^-97,1.60282*^-97,6.65567*^-98,2.76519*^-98,1.14936*^-98,4.77753*^-99,1.98643*^-99,8.26825*^-100,3.4443*^-100,1.43547*^-100,5.98552*^-101,2.49705*^-101,1.04227*^-101,4.3527*^-102,1.81875*^-102,7.6038*^-103,3.18078*^-103,1.33134*^-103,5.57575*^-104,2.33657*^-104,9.79784*^-105,4.11124*^-105,1.72629*^-105,7.25367*^-106,3.05037*^-106,1.28386*^-106,5.40825*^-107,2.28023*^-107,9.62247*^-108,4.06431*^-108,1.71825*^-108,7.2709*^-109,3.07963*^-109,1.30564*^-109,5.54077*^-110,2.35364*^-110,1.00079*^-110,4.25977*^-111,1.81498*^-111,7.74111*^-112,3.30513*^-112,1.42425*^-112,6.16014*^-113,2.62352*^-113,1.1185*^-113,4.77361*^-114,2.04521*^-114,8.7969*^-115,3.78806*^-115,1.63307*^-115,7.04855*^-116,3.04587*^-116,1.31808*^-116,5.71268*^-117,2.47975*^-117,1.07809*^-117,4.6944*^-118,2.04736*^-118,8.94306*^-119,3.90966*^-119,1.71011*^-119,7.48426*^-120,3.27728*^-120,1.4359*^-120,6.2948*^-121,2.76118*^-121,1.21189*^-121,5.32222*^-122,2.33877*^-122,1.02837*^-122}
```

I have tried three different approaches:

```
pars = FindDistributionParameters[Ftab,NormalDistribution[a1, a2],ParameterEstimator->"MethodOfMoments"];

(*{a1->2.61159*^19,a2->9.27508*^19}*)


epstab = Table[eps, {eps, 0, 50,.1}];

Ffit = FindFit[ Transpose@Join[{epstab}, {Ftab}], a1 PDF[NormalDistribution[a2, a3], eps],{a1, a2, a3}, eps]
(*{a1->1.,a2->1.,a3->1.} *)



nlm = NonlinearModelFit[Ftab, k Exp[-(eps - m1)^2/(2 s^2)], {m1, s, k}, eps];
(*{m1->1.,s->0.5,a3->1.} *)
```

However, these are not even close to the actual data.

I have tried even with the truncated data

```
Ftabsel=Select[Ftab, # >= 10^-21 &];
```

Pretty much the same.

Comment: While you only give a one-dimensional list of values, your data is (apparently) `data = Transpose[{Range[Length[Ftab]], Ftab}];`.  Therefore you have a regression that you want to perform with a normal curve shape as opposed to a random sample from a normal distribution.  In that case `FindDistributionParameters` is not at all what you want.

Comment: More specifically, `Transpose[{epstab, Ftab}]` with `epstab = Table[eps, {eps, 0, 50,.1}];`

Comment: Sorry, I should read more carefully.  That's exactly what you have in the question.  (The mixing up of regression and fitting a probability distribution tends to set me off.)

Comment: I tried `FindFit` which is supposed to do nonlinear regression, right?

Comment: Theoretically normal dist is never zero.

Comment: Can you add some detail as to how the data was collected?  In other words, are the values in 'Ftab' counts in each bin defined by `epstab`?  Or are the values in `Ftab` measurements over time with `epstab` representing time?  Or something else?  I ask because issue of deciding whether or not you have a regression or a binned random sample from some distribution.

Comment: @JimB `epstab` represents some discretization of energy axis, while `Ftab` contains corresponding values of inelastic collisions occurring in a gas. There are several hundreds of such terms, the sum of which enters the right hand side of a second order PDE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the following truncated data set:

```
epstab = Table[eps, {eps, 0, 50, .1}];
data = Transpose@Join[{epstab}, {Ftab}];
data = Select[data, 10 < #[[1]] < 20 &];
```

Now fit a normal/Gaussian shaped curve to that data:

```
nlm1 = NonlinearModelFit[data, a1 Exp[-(x - b1)^2/c1], {{a1, 5 10^20}, {b1, 15}, {c1, 2}}, x];

nlm1["EstimatedVariance"]^0.5
(* 1.29432*10^19 *)

Show[ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> All], Plot[nlm1[x], {x, 10, 20}]]
```

[image: Data and fit with 1 Gaussian-shaped curve]

Now plot the residuals vs the predictors to see more clearly where the lack-of-fit is located:

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{data[[All, 1]], nlm1["FitResiduals"]}], 
 PlotRange -> {All, {-5 10^19, 5 10^19}}, Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {"x", "Residual"}]
```

[image: Residuals vs predictors for 1 gaussian-shaped curve]

If that fit is good enough with respect to your fit criteria, then you are done.
But if not, suppose we add in another Gaussian-shaped curve:

```
nlm2 = NonlinearModelFit[data, a1 Exp[-(x - b1)^2/c1] + a2 Exp[-(x - b2)^2/c2],
  {{a1, 5 10^20}, {a2, 10^20}, {b1, 15}, {b2, 13.5}, {c1, 2}, {c2, 0.26}}, x];

nlm2["EstimatedVariance"]^0.5
(* 4.47305*10^18 *)
```

This measure of goodness-of-fit is about one-third the size of the previous model.  The residuals vs the predictors looks like the following:

```
Show[ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> All], Plot[nlm2[x], {x, 10, 20}]]
```

[image: Data and fit for 2 Gaussian-shaped curves]

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{data[[All, 1]], nlm2["FitResiduals"]}], 
 PlotRange -> {All, {-5 10^19, 5 10^19}}, Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {"x", "Residual"}]
```

[image: Residuals vs predicted values for 2 Gaussian-shaped curves]

Is that adequate?  I don't know.

Comment: Say, I have 100 sets of data and want to repeat what you did. Is there a way to pick the endpoints `10` and `20`, as well as the mean and the variance in some sense automatic?

Comment: I used `EmpiricalDistribution` from @Roman answer and substituted the initial guesses for `a1` by `Max@Ftab`, for `b1` by `Mean[d]` and for `c1` by `StandardDeviation[d]`. At the same time, I have updated your function as follows: `a1/Sqrt[2Pi]/StandardDeviation[d] Exp[-(eps - b1)^2/c1^2]`.

Answer (score 5):

**Edit 2:**

You can also multiply the model by max of the original data to fit the original data.

```
Show[ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> All], 
 Plot[max nlm[x - zeros], {x, 0, 500}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
  PlotRange -> All], Frame -> True]
```

[image]
**Edit:**

The issue is 0.'s. We can ignore them, and shift the model by the number of 0.'s

```
zeros = Count[data, 0.]
```

> 117

We can truncate zeros and normalize the data.

```
data = data/Max@data;
dataTrancated = Select[Ftab, # >= 10^-122 &];

nlm = NonlinearModelFit[dataTrancated, 
   k Exp[-(1/2) ((x - m)/s)^2], {m, s, k}, x, 
   Method -> {"NMinimize", Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"}];
Normal[nlm]

Show[ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> All], 
 Plot[nlm[x - zeros], {x, 0, 500}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
  PlotRange -> All], Frame -> True]
```

[image]
**Original Answer:**
You can normalize the data and truncate it.

```
Ftab = Ftab/Max@Ftab;
Ftab = Select[Ftab, # >= 10^-20 &];

nlm = NonlinearModelFit[Ftab, k Exp[-(1/2) ((x - m)/s)^2], {m, s, k}, 
  x, Method -> {"NMinimize", Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"}];
Normal[nlm]
```

> $1.00685 e^{-0.00432893 (x-32.3828)^2}$

```
Show[ListPlot[Ftab], Plot[nlm[x], {x, 0, 120}, PlotStyle -> Red], 
 Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution indeed works. Thanks. Due to the truncation, the peak of the fit has been shifted from the actual data to the right. Is there a way to transform it and obtain a fit for the initial data?

Comment: @AsaturKhurshudyan  What are your criteria for an adequate fit?  Is there something concrete or is it "I'll know it when I see it."

Comment: @JimB That's a good question I hadn't asked to myself. I think, minimum l2 norm should work.

Comment: That's a reasonable criterion.  Now:  what value of that would result in an adequate fit?

Comment: @JimB I would expect it to be small in the vicinity of the peak, e.g., `0.01`. For, the total l2 norm should be quite big.

Answer (score 2):

Build a distribution that represents your data:

```
d = EmpiricalDistribution[Ftab -> Range[0, 50, 1/10]];
```

Construct a normal distribution with the same mean and standard deviation:

```
n = NormalDistribution[Mean[d], StandardDeviation[d]]
(*    NormalDistribution[14.8267, 1.01774]    *)
```

Show that the cumulative distribution functions differ by less than 3%, which is great (see [Kolmogorov–Smirnov test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test)):

```
Plot[CDF[d, x] - CDF[n, x], {x, 0, 50}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: If `Ftab` is considered proportional to the counts associated with the 501 categories (assuming this set of data is a random sample from some distribution), then the Kolmogorov-Smirnov statistic is certainly a measure of the goodness-of-fit.  However, because the sample size is unknown, the associated P-value cannot be determined.  But if the smallest non-zero value (1.02837 * 10^-122) is associated even with a count of 1, then the P-value will be essentially zero as the sample size would have to be 1.27231 * 10^144.

Comment: @JimB That's exactly why I did not compute a P-value. What I show is, however, inspired by Kolmogorov–Smirnov as we're comparing two CDF.

Answer (score 2):

```
data = Ftab  // Chop // N ;

(* normalize data *)
peak = Max[data]  ;
norm = data/peak ;

(* mean initial guess *)
mean =First[Flatten[ Position[norm, Max[norm]]]]  ;

(* sigma initial guess *)
{a, b} =  Select[norm, # > 0.5*norm[[mean]] &][[{1, -1}]] ;
{min, max} =Sort[ Map[First[Flatten[Position[norm, #]]] &, {a, b}]] ;
fwhm = max - min ;
sigma = fwhm/2.36 ;

(* select data *)
factor = 3 ;
{min, max} = Floor[{ mean - factor*sigma ,  mean + factor*sigma }] ;
x = Range[min, max] ;
y = Take[norm, {min, max}] ;

(* fit *)
fit = NonlinearModelFit[Transpose[{x, y}], const*Exp[-(t - m)^2/(2*s^2)], {{m, mean}, {s, sigma}, {const, 1.0}}, t] ;
fit["BestFitParameters"]

Show[ListPlot[data, PlotRange->{{min, max}, All}], Plot[peak*fit[t], {t, min, max}]]
```

Comment: What is `1/2.36` in the definition of `sigma`?

Comment: Your solution works, thanks. However, it is shifted to the right and the horizontal axis is not with my initial `epstab`.

Comment: @AsaturKhurshudyan, 2.36 is a relation between [fwhm and sigma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_width_at_half_maximum#:~:text=In%20a%20distribution%2C%20full%20width,half%20of%20its%20maximum%20value.)

Comment: I don't get it, sorry

Comment: @AsaturKhurshudyan, not sure what you mean by 'sighted to the right'. My point here is you need a good initial guess for parameters for nonlinear fit to work well. Mean, sigma and data range initial values estimation can be automated. Initial guess for sigma can be inferred from fwhm.